# How to scroll an iframe containing a pdf in Ipad/iPhone/iOS?

Tags: ipad, iframe

I have a pdf embedded through an iframe using the media plugin. When you bring it up on the ipad, the iframe does not stretch to fit the content of the pdf.

At this point I am simply running a test to see what I get.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./ipad_files/jquery-1.7.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./ipad_files/media.js"></script>
    <style>
        iframe{width:550px; height:100%;}
        .media{width:630px !important; height:600px; overflow:scroll; -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;}
        *:not(html) {
            -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
            }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div style="width:650px; height:630px;">
        <a href="ipad_files/History-of-Cars.pdf" class="media">PDF LINK</a>
    </div>    
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $('.media').media();
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Whats rendered in the browser is a iframe.

Any ideas how I can scroll the iframe/containing div?  I know that I can't scroll the iframe but the iframe isn't expanding out.

Answer (score 0):

i've never used it but maybe [iScroll4](http://cubiq.org/iscroll-4) will fix your problem...